# duplicates rows while fetching the data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:  product, subscription and customer

```
SELECT id_product, product_sku

FROM product  

JOIN (select fk_product_subscribed, fk_customer from subscription

            where subscription.status = 'active')S  

    ON S.fk_product_subscribed = product.id_product  

JOIN (select id_customer from customer  

            where email = 'ashutosh@gmail.com')C  

    ON C.id_customer = S.fk_customer;
```

The result which I'm getting is:

```
+ ---------- + ----------------------- +
| id_product | product_sku             |
+ ---------- + ----------------------- +
| 100        | veggie for 3 happy meal |
| 100        | veggie for 3 happy meal |
+ ---------- + ----------------------- +
```

Why I am getting 2 rows instead of one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause there are multiple matches present while you `JOIN`. In this particular case you can use `distinct` saying `SELECT distinct id_product, product_sku` instead. Moreover, don't see any reason for the column selection in your subquery; you can probably perform a direct join there.

Your query can be like

```
SELECT distinct id_product, product_sku

FROM product p

JOIN subscription s

    ON s.fk_product_subscribed = p.id_product  

JOIN customer c ON c.id_customer = s.fk_customer

where s.status = 'active'
and c.email = 'ashutosh@gmail.com';
```

Comment: I did this too, 
SELECT id_product, product_sku
FROM product
    JOIN subscription
        ON subscription.fk_product_subscribed = product.id_product
    JOIN customer
        ON customer.id_customer = subscription.fk_customer
WHERE customer.email = ‘ashutosh@gmail.com’ 
AND subscription.status = ‘active’;
Still the same result

Comment: Yeah on distinct I am getting the correct result even from my query too. I need to understand why without distinct I am getting two rows there. I am pretty new here

Comment: @ashutoshsingh, read answer ... sole reason you getting dupes cause there are multiple match and thus join is producing all of them

Comment: it means I always have to use distinct whenever I have more than one join condition ?

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate duplicates by adding distinct to Select
SELECT DISTINCT id_product, product_sku

FROM product  ....

that way if customer has ordered product more than once, you will only get result once